# COdeIgniter structure for login & registration

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, design-principles

I am creating a login & registration system using CodeIgniter.

Currently I have a Model, View and Controller for login, with functions to validate,
check username, etc and an registration model, view and controller, 
that does the registration.

I have chosen to separate the login and registration as a principle.

So right now i need to include functions to *edit profile, and to check if logged in or not, and to check the user's role,* and I would like to know how can i best do this, i have planned creating a user model and controller(no view), the main user controller would have the methods call to model's, but however the methods(updateprofile,islogin,etc) would be in different models, for example in the login model.

So is this design good/bad? How can it be done better. I would appreciate your suggestion's.

Comment: First of all, CI implements `Model-View-Presenter`, not `MVC`. If you have a class that contains "Model" then you end up violating the `SRP`. If you want to develop a robust application, then quit using CI. Learn Zend2 or Symfony2

Comment: @DaveJust , I don't even think it's MVP. If you read the [definition of the pattern](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf) what CI uses is quite different. The closest similar "pattern" you can compare CodeIgniter with is Rails 1.x, but even then in there are significant differences.

Answer (score 0):

I really find no problem with your application structure. Its how you write your code and how will it easily be to update it in the future. For managing your models try using an ORM. PHPActiveRecord is a good start. With this, you no longer be creating alot of individual functions for your database transactions.  [Reference](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `User_Model` and expand it as needed. You can see this [CI auth lib](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) for example as how build login & registration structure in CodeIgniter.